# I can't get this jQuery animation that changes width to run more than one time

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want is for the user to be able to click a `<div>`. One clicked the `<div>` expands. Then, if the div is clicked again, it will retract back to its original width.

What happens instead is the div will expand with the first click. However, it will not retract on the second click. I have confirmed using `console.log()` that the click event is occurring, but the animation won't run again. As well, if I run a function at the end of the animation that calls a `console.log()`, that function runs as well, but the `<div>` still doesn't change size. I have tried this many different ways now.

Here is one such attempt below. I have also tried using removeClass().addClass() and having two different click events, but that had the same problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 1;
  var modulo = 1;

 $("#animateMe").click(function() {
   modulo = count % 2;
   count += 1;
   $("#animateMe").animate({
     width: (modulo = 0 ? 500 : 250)
   });
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="animateMe"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#animateMe  {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/ethan-vernon/pen/mLqBxR

Comment: `modulo = 0 ? 500 : 250` you're going to **compare** if `modulo` equals `0`, not **assign** `0` to `modulo`. So it should be `modulo == 0 ? 500 : 250`

Comment: you just update `modulo = 0` to `modulo == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition to `modulo == 0` as with `modulo = 0` you are always assigning the value of `modulo` to `0` and it results to `false` which assigns the width value to `250` in each click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 1;
  var modulo = 1;
   
  $("#animateMe").click(function() {
    modulo = count % 2;
    count += 1;
    $("#animateMe").animate(
      {
        width: (modulo == 0 ? 500 : 250)
      }
      
    );
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
/*
#animateMe {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 60px;
}
*/

#animateMe  {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animateMe">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other users you are trying to make an assignment instead of comparison: as a good practice it's better to use triple equality (`===`) and avoid convoluted syntax for better readability

```
if (modulo === 0) {
   width = 500
}
else {
   width = 250
}
```

you could also avoid to check the `modulo` variable and use a simple assignment, following your logic

```
$("#animateMe").animate({
   width : 500 - (modulo * 250)
});
```

or even

```
$("#animateMe").animate({
   width : [500, 250][modulo]
});
```

(since `modulo` can be only `0` or `1`)

---

> I have also tried using removeClass().addClass() and having two different click events, but that had the same problem.

A single click event listener, toggling just on class is enough: you could use only vanillaJS and CSS transition like so.

**CSS**

```
#animateMe  {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  transition: width 1s 0s;
}

#animateMe.half {
  width: 250px;
}
```

JS

```
var el = document.getElementById('animateMe');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.classList.toggle('half') 
});
```

> [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLpENG?editors=0110)